# Obtain the state of system background download

Tags: android, download

The system connects net using wifi and downloads a file. It will obtain the state of download process. The download process is STATUS_FAILED, STATUS_PAUSED, STATUS_PENDING, STATUS_RUNNING, and STATUS_SUCCESSFUL.

I want to use broadcast mechanism, receive the download radio from system.
And then get the download state with DownloadManager related method.  But it is failed. Could you give me some idea? Thanks!